# Must I call Looper.prepare() in a thread?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've searched for the relationship between thread and looper, and I just know what the two words's literal meaning now. When come to specific conditions, I'm still a little confused.

I came across this issue when I try to build an app about communicating with a bluetooth device. I got problems in the connect thread.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private String mSocketType;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            tip("Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed");
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothThreads.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

this code is download from the Android Developers's sample. and the Looper.prepare(), Looper.loop() are added by myself. Withou calling these two methods, the app will crash down. And I got a warning from the android studio:Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(). That's why I add the two methods.

I want to ask, do I call the two methods in the right way?

Why I must call them while I have not used Toast or Handler as others do?

Comment: Can you please include the link from where you have taken this code .

Comment: [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) this is the link from where I downloaded the sample code. And I have to mention that I have run the sample on my phone successfully. But When I try to build a new project similar to the sample on my own, I get trouble in the ConnectThread.

Comment: Check that your build.gradle file (available inside app folder) is similar to sample's buid.gradle file (available inside Application folder ) . While doing comparison do focus on sdk versions mentioned in the gradle file .

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ask, do I call the two methods in the right way?

Yes

> Why I must call them while I have not used Toast or Handler as others do?

`Looper.loop()` and `Looper().prepare()` are used to create a `MessageQueue` and to handle this `MessageQueue` android recommends to use `Handler` , so if you use `Looper.loop()` and `Looper.prepare()` then you should use `Handler` also .

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I appreciate that.

Comment: I upload my newly build project to git , here is the link [My Project](https://github.com/wtswzyw/YFCup2), if you don't bother to have a look. Actually I'm still confused why the sample code can run without crashing down and my own similar project cannot. In fact I don't want handle the message from ConnectThread, all I want ConnectThread to do is connect a bluetooth device and return me a socket.

Comment: Make app/build.gradle file  similar to the sample's Application/build.gradle file .

Comment: If you are still getting problem then put it here .

Comment: To make app/build.gradle file similar to the sample's Application/build.gradle file, I simply add the part that is in the later file but not in the former file to the former file. And things changed. Before I changed the .gradle file, I have never connect to a device(computer or headset). I used to think it's UUID's bad, or because of my not using the right profile class. But today I get a active response from the device I want to connect, I successfully connected to a headset's bluetooth. Besides, app will still crash down when I try to connect a device if I comment Looper.prepare().

Comment: I know that build.gradle file is used to illustrate how to build my app, but I don't know how it changed my project after I changed it. I have uploaded the [updatedProject](https://github.com/wtswzyw/YFCup2) to github.

Comment: Make minSdkVersion 11 in your app/build.gradle file

Comment: Download modified build.gradle form https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmno29gbj8aickw/build.gradle?dl=0 and put inside app folder

Comment: Well, thank you! Would you please send the build.gradle file to my mailbox(249842719@qq.com)? Because I'm in China, and the government's GFW forbid me to visit dropbox.

Comment: I noticed that there is only one difference between yours build.gradle and my build.gradle. In your build.gradle file, "cardview" is used, and my build.gradle uses the "appcompat", and I also have to change the styles.xml. So do you think it's the difference between the two package is the answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I figure out what's wrong with my own project. There is nothing to do with the build.gradle, but thank **Android Dev** all the same.

Actually it's myself to blame. In the sample project [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html), methods like `Log.d()` is called to indicate the debug information. But I didn't know where to find `Log.d()`'s result, so I replaced them with `Toast`. I thought that would be fine. But I find out that `Toast` cannot be used in `ConnectThread`, otherwise it will throw an Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

And I used `Toast` in method `connectionFailed()`, that's where the problem is.

Comment: But there is no Toast in the code you have mentioned above . Toast will create problem inside worker thread since it requires UI thread .

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do *not* need `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()`. Those are only required when you would like to attach a `Handler` to the thread, which in your case, I cannot see such requirement.

Essentially, Once you call `Looper.prepare()`, It assigns a message queue to this thread such that all subsequent messages passed by handlers will be handled one by one in a queue manner.

**Note:** For debugging always use `Log.d()` / `Log.w()` / `Log.e()` and avoid using toasts.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that now